# Tizen-web-ui-fw.js is not working (Tizen)

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

I am developing an app for tizen. I have a div in which i am showing text. Text may be large than the div so for this i am using overflow:auto/scroll to make div scrollable.

Now this is perfectly showing on eclipse html view but when i run my code on tizen device i don't see any scrollbars.

Now for this i have come to know from my posted [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580512/how-to-make-div-scrollable-using-javascript/16581280?noredirect=1#16581280) that i have to enable scrolling in tizen. for this i need tizen-web-ui-fw.js file which i download from [link](http://searchco.de/codesearch/raw/27622046).

And follow the instruction from tizen developer guide. But when app run on my device i see error message on console that

> js/tizen-web-ui-fw.js (156) :TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object

**which is on line    :**

> (function ( $, window, document, undefined )

Now what i have to change or any other relible link for downloading the file tizen-web-ui-fw.js. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my steps which i followed:

```
  <head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="my-configure.js></script>
<script src="tizen-web-ui-fw/0.1/js/tizen-web-ui-fw.js" data-framework-theme="tizen-gray"></script>
<script src="myapp.js></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there "0.1" directory under "tizen-web-ui-fw"? You can check it from "Project Explorer" in Tizen SDK. "{Project}\tizen-web-ui-fw". For me, only **latest** directory is shown.

So I use

```
<script src="tizen-web-ui-fw/latest/js/tizen-web-ui-fw.js" ...></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="tizen-web-ui-fw/0.1/js/tizen-web-ui-fw.js" ...></script>
```

Comment: Actulllay i found that folder but when i include it in my html still it is giving "undefined is not an object"

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the latest tizen-web-ui-fw.js (now called TAU) but can't find the message like that. And I can even simply use `overflow: auto` or `scroll` to make a scrollable div with the latest.